# I'm creating Android layout but after running on my real device i'm getting unique view of same layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an main activity in which I have creating layout in XML in Android Studio and setting width and height properly as per my need but after executing my code on my device I'm getting a different view of the same layout.

And also I want to do scroll up my layout when my keyboard is active but after adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` not help me.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_zcrt_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/splash1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_layout_border">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/login_logo" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/lay_login_border"
                app:cardCornerRadius="14dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Login"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_phone_number"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:hint="Mobile"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="10" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_corner"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:text="Submit"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Here you can see from images I search a lot on a community but not getting any single article related to this.

[This is my android studio layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40etr.jpg)

[This is my real device view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nntFO.jpg)

Comment: Give necessary padding inside your card view  eg: android:padding=10dp

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_width` to `match_parent`, and then add marginStart & marginEnd